# visibility expression in report builder with multiple hidden values

Tags: sql, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have an image that i would like to hide based on a value. This value can have 3 possible returns. "AP02", "AP16", "" (blank). I want the image visible only if the value is "AP16"

Currently i am using this code:

```
=First(Fields!LastMPClientName.Value, "ClientSummary")="AP02"
```

The above works if the value is "AP02" however i am seeing more and more blank values for my clients.

How can i make this image hidden for both "AP02" and "" values?

I am using report builder 3.0 from a SQL 2008R2 instance.

Comment: Cant you use an OR?   =First(Fields!LastMPClientName.Value, "ClientSummary")="AP02" OR First(Fields!LastMPClientName.Value, "ClientSummary")=""

Comment: Thanks TMNT2014! That does work. I like simple answers.

i had tried =First(Fields!LastMPClientName.Value, "ClientSummary")="AP02" OR "" but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cant you use an OR?

```
=First(Fields!LastMPClientName.Value, "ClientSummary")="AP02" OR First(Fields!LastMPClientName.Value, "ClientSummary")=""
```